# Is the C# pure object-oriented programming language?

Tags: c#, .net

I recently start to learn C# and I want to know whether the C# is Pure Object-Oriented with reason in both the cases(cases yes or no).

Comment: What a Pure-OO language is?

Comment: If by "Pure Object-Oriented" you mean "nothing can exist outside of an object".. then I guess thats a yes.

Comment: As per blog [Programming Language Comparison](http://www.jvoegele.com/software/langcomp.html) its Hybrid

Comment: Yes it is is pure Object programming  language because it holds All four properties..                                          Abstraction,
Encapsulation,
Polymorphism,
Inheritance. It also has feature that are not strictly Object oriented like...                                             Enum,Enums
Value types
Static methods
Static classes

Comment: @Satpal What is that blogs definition of "pre-defined types"? In C#, all primitives are considered objects.. so, if primatives are "pre-defined types".. then that blog is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not %100 sure exactly the meaning of *"pure" object-oriented* but my answer is YES.

From [Smaltalks wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk);

> Smalltalk is a "pure" object-oriented programming language, meaning
>   that, unlike Java and C++, there is no difference between values which
>   are objects and values which are primitive types. In Smalltalk,
>   **primitive values such as integers, booleans and characters are also
>   objects,**

That is the same as in C#.

I found an interesting article called [`Wyvern: A Simple, Typed, and Pure Object-Oriented Language`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dkurilov/maspeghi13.pdf)

> 1.1 What Makes an Object-Oriented Model Pure?
>
> From these sources, we extract three key requirements that we wish to
>   satisfy in coming up with a typed, pure object-oriented model:
>
> - Uniform access principle. Following Meyer, Cook, and Kay, it should be possible to access objects only by invoking their methods.
> - Interoperability and uniform treatment. Different implementations of the same object oriented interface should interoperate by default,
>     and it should be easy to treat them uniformly at run time (e.g., by
>     storing different implementations of the same interface within a
>     single run-time data structure).
> - State encapsulation. All mutable state should be encapsulated within objects.